# Android using data transfer protocol http or https

Tags: android, protocols, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

How can I use in debug mode `HttpUrlConnection`, but when release mode use `HttpsUrlConnection`. Something like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.Debug) {
    conn = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
} else {
    conn = (HttpsUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
}
```

Comment: If you do this, make sure that you verify that your app is using HTTPS before you release new production versions of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Create endpoint constant in `gradle.build`

```
def var_api_base_url = "API_BASE_URL"

debug {
    buildConfigField "String", var_api_base_url, "\"http://url\""
}

release {
    buildConfigField "String", var_api_base_url, "\"https://url\""   
}
```

To use url `BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL`

Answer (score 0):

The `URL.openConnection()` method, returns a new connection to the resource referred to by the URL, so you need to make sure that the url is a http or https resource.